# How to make a div tag move based on its CSS transform: rotate(); property?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m trying to code a mobile game in which you must drive a car, so I have made a separate file as a library of sorts. The problem is how to I calculate how to move forward using the `orient` variable to find out which way is forward. I would have tried to add this, but I had no clue where to start :/ any help is appreciated! Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title Here</title>
        <!-- CSS --!>
        <style>
            #character {
                position: relative;
                transform: rotate(0deg);
                width: 50px;
                height: 75px;
                background-color: red;
                top: 50px;
                left: 50px;
            }
            
            #left {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 3px;
                left: 3px;
                width: 125px;
                height: 125px;
                background-color: red;
                text-align: center;
            }
            
            #right {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 3px;
                right: 3px;
                width: 125px;
                height: 125px;
                background-color: red;
                text-align: center;
            }
            
            #drive
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="character">
            <div style="width: 44px; height: 22px; background-color: blue; margin: 3px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="left" onclick="left()"></div>
        <div id="right" onclick="right()"></div>
        <!-- JS --!>
        <script>
            // variables go here
            
            var pos;
            var orient = 0;
            
            // initialiser function
            
            function init() {
                
                Update();
            }
            
            //start the game
            
            init();
            
            // Updating function (this occurs when an action is completed)
            
            function Update() {
                
            }
            
            // Character controller goes here
            
            function left() {
                orient -= 10;   
                document.getElementById("character").style.transform = "rotate(" + orient + "deg)";
                Update();
            }
            function right() {
                orient += 10;   
                document.getElementById("character").style.transform = "rotate(" + orient + "deg)";
                Update();
            }
            function fwd() {
                pos += 
                document.getElementById("character").style.top = "1000px";
                Update();
            }
            
            //functions go here
            
            
            
            // oninput tags go here
            
            
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you also know how to make the code able to run, please tell me how to do so in the comments!

Answer (score 1):

You can use transform: translate(X,Y).

Here, you have to calculate X and, Y based on rotation of CAR and, initial position. Also, you can have you own velocity and acceleration for it.

Comment: I am already using the transform CSS property so if I used that, wouldn’t that reset the rotate(deg) property?

Comment: No you can get that and, use the string operations to make sure that doesn't get lost. Alternatively, you can use transform as template containing rotate(2) translate(30,40). No just replace the data between brackets

Comment: Using JS you can get transform property, then you can use regex/string operation to extract and replace the current data. It will always be of rotate(n) translate(X,Y)

Comment: The `transform: translate(0px,0px);` property is similar to my `top: 0px; left: 0px;` method, and it would be too confusing because I have worked with that method for too long.

Comment: Yeah you can also use top as Y value and, left as X value.